Millennial reign and New Heaven and New Earth
Why does Revelation 21:1 talks about the new heavens and new earth after the millennial reign described in Revelation 20 while Isaiah 65 seems to indicate that the new heavens and earth come first before the millennial reign because there is still death on Earth (vs20) at that point? The end of Revelation indicates that death is gone seemingly after the millennial reign when the new heavens and earth are created.

Now I saw a new heaven and a new earth, for the first heaven and the first earth had passed away. Also there was no more sea. (Revelation 21:1 NKJV)


“For behold, I create new heavens and a new earth; And the former shall not be remembered or come to mind. “No more shall an infant from there live but a few days, Nor an old man who has not fulfilled his days; For the child shall die one hundred years old, But the sinner being one hundred years old shall be accursed. They shall build houses and inhabit them; They shall plant vineyards and eat their fruit. They shall not build and another inhabit; They shall not plant and another eat; For as the days of a tree, so shall be the days of My people, And My elect shall long enjoy the work of their hands. They shall not labor in vain, Nor bring forth children for trouble; For they shall be the descendants of the blessed of the Lord, And their offspring with them. “It shall come to pass That before they call, I will answer; And while they are still speaking, I will hear. The wolf and the lamb shall feed together, The lion shall eat straw like the ox, And dust shall be the serpent’s food. They shall not hurt nor destroy in all My holy mountain,” Says the Lord.
(Isaiah 65:17‭, ‬20‭-‬25 NKJV)


Welcome to SE-C. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the 17,000 archived question/answer contributions as to how these policies play out in practice.

The best explanation of 'The Revelation of Jesus Christ' (which is the full and proper title of the book written by John the Apostle) that I know of,  is that given by John Metcalfe in his book of the same title which is Volume V111 of his series 'The Apostolic Foundation of the Christian Church'.
He firstly lists the common ways in which the book is viewed (Praeterist, Historicist, Futurist and Resumptive) and then goes on (in over 600 detailed pages) to give a full account of the Resumptive view which sees the book as seven recurring passes across the entire Church Age.
These seven aspects of the book view the age from the ascension of Jesus Christ to his return ; in higher and higher spiritual ways.
Looking at the entire age in prophecy is too complex for us to understand so the visions of John (says the Resumptive view) help us by seeing one aspect of the age across the whole age before returning to the beginning and passing again through the same period of time from ascension to return of Jesus Christ.
John Metcalfe likens the reading of the prophecy of John to looking at a mountain from the distance and seeing seven sheep-trods crossing the mountain from one side to the other at different elevations.
The higher up the mountain, the shorter and yet the higher (a higher spiritual view, as it were) does one perceive the sheep paths cross the mountain's side.
I think this is why you are seeing a repetition and it is clear that you have made a proper study of John's book to be able to have seen that.
The explanation given by John Metcalfe may, perhaps, be as compelling to yourself as it has been to myself.
See The Apostolic Foundation of the Christian Church Volume V111

John's first epistle is written in similar albeit much less exaggerated fashion.  It circles back over and over and is famously difficult to outline. +1

Explanations between the discripation between the new heavens and new earth described in Isaiah 65 (with death) and in Revelation 21 (without death) can become very complex when taking into account different possible interpretations between the meaning of the concepts of "new heavens", "new earth", "the first resurrection" (Rev 20:5,6) "Death and Hades" (Rev 20:14), "the second death-the lake of fire" (Rev 20:14, Rev 20:5).
However, a relatively neutral explanation can be based on the tenses of the verbs used.
The Hebrew phrase (bore) used in Isaiah 65 is a participle form of the verb "to create" and it can refer to

an imminent action
an action in progress
or a habitual action

Therefore various bible translations render Isaian 65:17 it a bit different. For example:

NIV “See, I will create new heavens and a new earth. The former things
will not be remembered, nor will they come to mind.


NLT “Look! I am creating new heavens and a new earth, and no one will
even think about the old ones anymore.

Note the imminent action "will be", or action in progress "am creating".
Now in contrast, lets look at some key points about the Greek from Revelation 21:1
"Εἶδον" (eidon) - "I saw" is in the aorist tense, indicating a completed action in the past.
"ἀπῆλθαν" (apēlthan) - "passed away" is also aorist tense, suggesting a completed action.
"οὐκ ἔστιν" (ouk estin) - "is no more" is in the present tense.

In this way, one could interpret Isaiah 65 (with death) as referring to the process of creating a new heaven and earth during the 1000 years, while in contrast, Revelation 21 can be seen as the state when the new heaven and earth are "ready" (without death) after the 1000 years have ended.
Maybe somewhat oversimplified lets illustrate the new heaven and earth as a pie, that is baking in an oven to get ready for a specific time. For a while its a pie in progress, and later its done, but all the time we can refer to it as a pie.

The new heaven and new earth of Isaiah 65 describe alegorically the messianic age, i.e. the interval between Christ's Ascension and Second Coming, whereas the new heaven and new earth of Revelation 21 describe alegorically the final state of the resurrected saved enjoying the Beatific Vision, after Christ's Second Coming, the universal resurrection, and the Final Judgment.
So, they are different pairs of (new heaven and new earth).
